# Detect a Null value in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsnull

I have an `NSDictionary` that's populated from a JSON response from an API server. Sometimes the values for a key in this dictionary are `Null`

I am trying to take the given value and drop it into the detail text of a table cell for display.

The problem is that when I try to coerce the value into an `NSString` I get a crash, which I *think* is because I'm trying to coerce `Null` into a string.

What's the right way to do this?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = sensor.objectForKey( "latestValue" ) as NSString
```

Here's an example of the Dictionary:

```
Printing description of sensor:
{
    "created_at" = "2012-10-10T22:19:50.501-07:00";
    desc = "<null>";
    id = 2;
    "latest_value" = "<null>";
    name = "AC Vent Temp";
    "sensor_type" = temp;
    slug = "ac-vent-temp";
    "updated_at" = "2013-11-17T15:34:27.495-07:00";
}
```

If I just need to wrap all of this in a conditional, that's fine. I just haven't been able to figure out what that conditional is. Back in the Objective-C world I would compare against `[NSNull null]` but that doesn't seem to be working in Swift.

Comment: `NSNull` the class exists in Swift, so you could compare to `NSNull()`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the `as?` operator, which returns an optional value (`nil` if the downcast fails)

```
if let latestValue = sensor["latestValue"] as? String {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = latestValue
}
```

I tested this example in a swift application

```
let x: AnyObject = NSNull()
if let y = x as? String {
    println("I should never be printed: \(y)")
} else {
    println("Yay")
}
```

and it correctly prints `"Yay"`, whereas

```
let x: AnyObject = "hello!"
if let y = x as? String {
    println(y)
} else {
    println("I should never be printed")
}
```

prints `"hello!"` as expected.

Comment: Will this work even if his value is actually an instance of `NSNull`?

Comment: @TimGostony unless the `as?` specification is misleading, yes, it will work, since the cast will fail.

Comment: When using the downcast, I get an error in the Playground about the `as?` usage: `Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Comment: @TimGostony I tried it in an app and it appears to work.

Comment: Did you try it fetching the object from a dictionary though?

Comment: @TimGostony I haven't, but I think that proves the point: if it's not a `String` it produces a `nil`.

Comment: To make this work on dictionary elements, at least in beta 3, you need to add a `!` after `sensor["latestValue"]` in the example, otherwise a cryptic compile-time error about String not being a subtype of (String, AnyObject) occurs. If you are not confident that "latestValue" is in the dictionary (even with an NSNull value), you’ll need to split out a separate optional-unpacking step first.

Comment: That saved some Time :)

Answer (score 37):

You could also use `is` to check for the presence of a null:

```
if sensor["latestValue"] is NSNull {
    // do something with null JSON value here
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm using this combination and it also checks if object is not `"null"`.

```swift
func isNotNull(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    guard let object = object else { return false }
    return isNotNSNull(object) && isNotStringNull(object)
}

func isNotNSNull(object: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    object.classForCoder != NSNull.classForCoder()
}

func isNotStringNull(object: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    guard let object = object as? String where object.uppercaseString == "NULL" else {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

It's not that pretty as extension but work as charm :)

Answer (score 9):

NSNull is a class like any other. Thus you can use `is` or `as` to test an AnyObject reference against it.

Thus, here in one of my apps I have an NSArray where every entry is either a Card or NSNull (because you can't put nil in an NSArray). I fetch the NSArray as an Array and cycle through it, switching on which kind of object I get:

```
for card:AnyObject in arr {
    switch card { // how to test for different possible types
    case let card as NSNull:
        // do one thing
    case let card as Card:
        // do a different thing
    default:
        fatalError("unexpected object in card array") // should never happen!
    }
}
```

That is not identical to your scenario, but it is from a working app converted to Swift, and illustrates the full general technique.

Answer (score 8):

my solution for now:

```
func isNull(someObject: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    guard let someObject = someObject else {
        return true
    }

    return (someObject is NSNull)
}
```

tests look good so far...

[image: tests look good so far]

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem and solved it with casting to the correct type of the original NSDictionary value. If your service returns a mixed type JSON object like this

```
{"id":2, "name":"AC Vent Temp", ...}
```

you'll have to fetch it's values like that.

```
var id:int = sensor.valueForKey("id") as Int;
var name:String? = sensor.valueForKey("name") as String;
```

This did solve my problem. See [BAD_INSTRUCTION within swift closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040691/bad-instruction-within-swift-closure)