# Swift. How can I deal with null values into json files?

Tags: ios, json, null, swift

I'm reading json from a URL and, again (I had the same issue with ObjectiveC) the  values crash my app. I don't have any problems with Strings and Numbers. I can println(value) but when I assign the value into a UILabel, it crashes.

I use this method to read the JSON:

```
func jsonFromURL(jsonURL: String) -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    var jsonNSURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: jsonURL)
    let jsonSource: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: jsonNSURL)
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonSource, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    return json
}
```

...and this code to assign values into a UILabel inside a custom Cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {

    var regularTextCell:celda = celda(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var cell:celda = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("celda", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as celda

    cell.name.text = myJson["list"]![indexPath.row]!["name"] as String
    cell.id.text = "id: " + String(myJson["list"]![indexPath.row]!["id"] as Int)

    // THIS line crash because some values of adress are <null>
    cell.address.text = myJson["list"]![indexPath.row]!["address"] as String

    return cell

}
```

You can view an example of the JSON at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/787784/example.json

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect a Null value in NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026609/detect-a-null-value-in-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll get an exception from syntax like `object as String` if `object` is not a `String`.  You can avoid the exception by using `object as? String` which may result in a `nil` being assigned into your `text`.

In your specific case you could use:

```
cell.address.text = (myJson["list"]![indexPath.row]!["address"] as? String) ?? "default"
```

where I've replaced your `as` with `as?` and exploited the nil-coalescing operator `??`.

Comment: if I do: let text = object as? String, "text" I can't call String methods on text as it is not recognized as a String

Comment: If `object` can't be coerced to a `String` then `text` will be `nil`.

Answer (score 9):

I found this solution in online Swift tutorial. It's very nice solution how to deal with null value in Swift.

This is the concept:

```
 let finalVariable = possiblyNilVariable ?? "Definitely Not Nil Variable"
```

In tutorial example :

```
  let thumbnailURL = result["artworkUrl60"] as? String ?? ""
```

Here is the link for tutorial: 
http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-8-apps-using-swift-interaction-with-multiple-views/

Comment: I tried to do this but i wanted to unwrap the values by doing  let thumbnailURL = (result["artworkUrl60"] as? String ?? "")! but didn't work is there a good way that while the assignment can i unwrap it? @Marijan V.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the offending line to:

```
if let address = myJson["list"]![indexPath.row]!["address"] as? String {
  cell.address.text = address
}
else {
  cell.address.text = ""
}
```

The `as?` operator will cast the value the same way `as` would, but if the casting fails, it will instead assign `nil`

The `if let …` syntax combines this with a check and when the casting fails (and nil is returned) the else block runs instead

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

- https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json/

You'll be able to go like this:

```
let yourJSON = JSON.fromURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/787784/example.json")
for (i, node) in yourJSON["list"] {
    let isnull = node["address"].isNull
    println("//[\"list\"][\(i)]:\t\(isnull)")
}

//["list"][0]:  false
//["list"][1]:  false
//["list"][2]:  true
//["list"][3]:  false
//["list"][4]:  false
//["list"][5]:  true
//["list"][6]:  false
//["list"][7]:  false
//["list"][8]:  false
//["list"][9]:  false
//["list"][10]: false
//["list"][11]: false
//["list"][12]: true
//["list"][13]: false
//["list"][14]: false
//["list"][15]: false
//["list"][16]: false
//["list"][17]: false
//["list"][18]: false
//["list"][19]: false
```

No `?` or `!` required and it does not crash on nonexistent nodes.