# Swift: How to remove a null value from Dictionary?

Tags: ios, json, swift, null, nsdictionary

I'm new in Swift and I have a problem with filtering NULL values from JSON file and setting it into Dictionary. 
I getting JSON response from the server with null values and it crashes my app.

Here is JSON response:

```
"FirstName": "Anvar",
"LastName": "Azizov",
"Website": null,
"About": null,
```

I will be very appreciated for help to deal with it.

**UPD1:** At this moment I decided to do it in a next way:

```
if let jsonResult = responseObject as? [String: AnyObject] {                    
    var jsonCleanDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()

    for (key, value) in enumerate(jsonResult) {
      if !(value.1 is NSNull) {
         jsonCleanDictionary[value.0] = value.1
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code/library are you using to interpret the json string? Is it being passed into a NSDictionary or some other container? A code example will help people understand better what you are trying to do and where the issue lies.

Comment: Instead of removing you should detect and handle the null values correctly. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026609/detect-a-null-value-in-nsdictionary.

Comment: @Graff, I'm using AfNetworking and the data passed into a NSDictionary. I decided to enumerate on values and delete all Null vallues. I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: As @MartinR has said, it's usually better to handle the null values properly rather than blindly filter them out. Can you show the code which is crashing? Then we can help solve that issue and the data doesn't need to be filtered.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### Swift 5

Use `compactMapValues`:

```
dictionary.compactMapValues { $0 }
```

`compactMapValues` has been introduced in Swift 5. For more info see Swift proposal [SE-0218](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0218-introduce-compact-map-values.md).

#### Example with dictionary

```
let json = [
    "FirstName": "Anvar",
    "LastName": "Azizov",
    "Website": nil,
    "About": nil,
]

let result = json.compactMapValues { $0 }
print(result) // ["FirstName": "Anvar", "LastName": "Azizov"]
```

#### Example including JSON parsing

```
let jsonText = """
  {
    "FirstName": "Anvar",
    "LastName": "Azizov",
    "Website": null,
    "About": null
  }
  """

let data = jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
if let json = json as? [String: Any?] {
    let result = json.compactMapValues { $0 }
    print(result) // ["FirstName": "Anvar", "LastName": "Azizov"]
}
```

### Swift 4

I would do it by combining `filter` with `mapValues`:

```
dictionary.filter { $0.value != nil }.mapValues { $0! }
```

#### Examples

Use the above examples just replace `let result` with

```
let result = json.filter { $0.value != nil }.mapValues { $0! }
```

Comment: Couln't not remove the `null` entry from valid json i.e:  `{ "something": [ { "name": "One" }, { "name": "Two" }, null ]}`

Comment: The question and my solution is about removing `null` from the root JSON dictionary. It does not remove all the `null`s inside the JSON. You want to remove `null` from an array that is a value inside root JSON dictionary. You can use this: `if let something = json["something"] as? [Any?] { print(something.compactMap { $0 is NSNull ? nil : $0 }) }`.
Note that JSONSerialization returns `NSNull` objects for `null` that are not automatically converted to `nil` when converting to Swift array `[Any?]`, therefore you need to check for `NSNull` explicitly.

Answer (score 15):

You can create an array containing the keys whose corresponding values are nil:

```
let keysToRemove = dict.keys.array.filter { dict[$0]! == nil }
```

and next loop through all elements of that array and remove the keys from the dictionary:

```
for key in keysToRemove {
    dict.removeValueForKey(key)
}
```

---

**Update 2017.01.17**

The force unwrapping operator is a bit ugly, although safe, as explained in the comments. There are probably several other ways to achieve the same result, a better-looking way of the same method is:

```
let keysToRemove = dict.keys.filter {
  guard let value = dict[$0] else { return false }
  return value == nil
}
```

Comment: the force unwrap is a wtf here. this is only not crashing because the value type is not an optional. also: never force unwrap at all

Comment: @Hogdotmac it's definitely not an elegant way of doing it nowadays, but take into account that `dict[$0]` is an optional which may contain another optional. The force unwrap is safe because we're looping through the array of keys, so each of these keys exists

Comment: Adding to @Antonio's point, force-unwrap will let compiler avoid unnecessary branching.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work for a valid json like this `{ "something": [ { "name": "One" }, { "name": "Two" }, null ]}`

Answer (score 8):

I ended up with this in **Swift 2**:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: AnyObject {

    var nullsRemoved: [Key: Value] {
        let tup = filter { !($0.1 is NSNull) }
        return tup.reduce([Key: Value]()) { (var r, e) in r[e.0] = e.1; return r }
    }
}
```

Same answer but for **Swift 3**:

```
extension Dictionary {

    /// An immutable version of update. Returns a new dictionary containing self's values and the key/value passed in.
    func updatedValue(_ value: Value, forKey key: Key) -> Dictionary<Key, Value> {
        var result = self
        result[key] = value
        return result
    }

    var nullsRemoved: [Key: Value] {
        let tup = filter { !($0.1 is NSNull) }
        return tup.reduce([Key: Value]()) { $0.0.updatedValue($0.1.value, forKey: $0.1.key) }
    }
}
```

Things get a lot easier in **Swift 4**. Just use Dictionary's `filter` directly.

```
jsonResult.filter { !($0.1 is NSNull) }
```

Or if you don't want to remove the relevant keys, you can do this:

```
jsonResult.mapValues { $0 is NSNull ? nil : $0 }
```

Which will replace the `NSNull` values with `nil` instead of removing the keys.

Comment: Pretty similar to what I came up with. Both `filter` and `reduce` iterate through the array so only using `reduce` will probably be a bit faster than using both of them. I like the idea of it being an extension.

Comment: And they are deprecating car in this context for Swift 3.

Comment: True, I updated my answer to account for that and to avoid creating a new copy of the dictionary on every iteration.

Comment: @DanielT i have used the above code for swift 2 but now I'm migrating to swift3 and I'm getting error "cannot assign through subscript: 'r' is a let constant". can u please help

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas I updated the answer with a Swift 3 version.

Comment: @DanielT I'm migrating above code to swift4. Please help me out with the code.

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas I added it to the answer.

Comment: @DanielT. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Swift5**

Use compactMapValues to create a dictionary extension for future usage

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Optional<Any> {
    func discardNil() -> [Key: Any] {
        return self.compactMapValues({ $0 })
    }
}
```

How to use

```
public func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    let emailAddress: String? = "test@mail.com"
    let phoneNumber: String? = "xxx-xxx-xxxxx"
    let newPassword: String = "**********"

    return [
        "emailAddress": emailAddress,
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
        "passwordNew": newPassword
    ].discardNil()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you just want to filter out any `NSNull` values from a dictionary, this is probably one of the better ways of going about it. It's future-proofed against Swift 3, as far as I know for now:

(With thanks to [AirspeedVelocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/07/19/jumping-to-conclusions/) for the extension, translated to Swift 2)

```
import Foundation

extension Dictionary {
/// Constructs [key:value] from [(key, value)]

  init<S: SequenceType
    where S.Generator.Element == Element>
    (_ seq: S) {
      self.init()
      self.merge(seq)
  }

  mutating func merge<S: SequenceType
    where S.Generator.Element == Element>
    (seq: S) {
      var gen = seq.generate()
      while let (k, v) = gen.next() {
        self[k] = v
      }
  }
}

let jsonResult:[String: AnyObject] = [
  "FirstName": "Anvar",
  "LastName" : "Azizov",
  "Website"  : NSNull(),
  "About"    : NSNull()]

// using the extension to convert the array returned from flatmap into a dictionary
let clean:[String: AnyObject] = Dictionary(
  jsonResult.flatMap(){ 
    // convert NSNull to unset optional
    // flatmap filters unset optionals
    return ($0.1 is NSNull) ? .None : $0
  })
// clean -> ["LastName": "Azizov", "FirstName": "Anvar"]
```

Comment: In Swift 2, `jsonResult.filter { !($0.1 is NSNull) }` comes back with a type of [(String: AnyObject)] rather than [String: AnyObject]... Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit trickier. The easiest way to do it is with `reduce` although there are other ways to go about it. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Suggesting this approach, flattens optional values and also compatible with Swift 3

`String` key, optional `AnyObject?` value dictionary with nil values:

```
let nullableValueDict: [String : AnyObject?] = [
    "first": 1,
    "second": "2",
    "third": nil
]

// ["first": {Some 1}, "second": {Some "2"}, "third": nil]
```

nil values removed and transformed into non optional value dictionary

```
nullableValueDict.reduce([String : AnyObject]()) { (dict, e) in
    guard let value = e.1 else { return dict }
    var dict = dict
    dict[e.0] = value
    return dict
}

// ["first": 1, "second": "2"]
```

Redeclaration `var dict = dict` is needed due to removal of var parameters in swift 3, so for swift 2,1 it could be;

```
nullableValueDict.reduce([String : AnyObject]()) { (var dict, e) in
    guard let value = e.1 else { return dict }
    dict[e.0] = value
    return dict
}
```

Swift 4, would be;

```
let nullableValueDict: [String : Any?] = [
    "first": 1,
    "second": "2",
    "third": nil
]

let dictWithoutNilValues = nullableValueDict.reduce([String : Any]()) { (dict, e) in
    guard let value = e.1 else { return dict }
    var dict = dict
    dict[e.0] = value
    return dict
}
```

Comment: What would this look like in Swift 4?

Comment: Hey @adrian i updated the answer with Swift 4 compatible. See [Swift Sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a213dfe3d51ff687fc49fdd)

Answer (score 3):

### Swift 5

> **compactMapValues(_:)**
>
> Returns a new dictionary containing only the key-value pairs that have
>   non-nil values as the result of transformation by the given closure.

```
let people = [
    "Paul": 38,
    "Sophie": 8,
    "Charlotte": 5,
    "William": nil
]

let knownAges = people.compactMapValues { $0 }
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work for a valid json like this `{ "something": [ { "name": "One" }, { "name": "Two" }, null ]}`

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the null values to empty string by following function.

```
func removeNullFromDict (dict : NSMutableDictionary) -> NSMutableDictionary
{
    let dic = dict;

    for (key, value) in dict {

        let val : NSObject = value as! NSObject;
        if(val.isEqual(NSNull()))
        {
            dic.setValue("", forKey: (key as? String)!)
        }
        else
        {
            dic.setValue(value, forKey: key as! String)
        }

    }

    return dic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Swift 4 provides method `reduce(into:_:)` for class `Dictionary` you can remove nil-values from `Dictionary` with the following function:

```
func removeNilValues<K,V>(dict:Dictionary<K,V?>) -> Dictionary<K,V> {

    return dict.reduce(into: Dictionary<K,V>()) { (currentResult, currentKV) in

        if let val = currentKV.value {

            currentResult.updateValue(val, forKey: currentKV.key)
        }
    }
}
```

You can test it like that:

```
let testingDict = removeNilValues(dict: ["1":nil, "2":"b", "3":nil, "4":nil, "5":"e"])
print("test result is \(testingDict)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another quick way to do it in case you're not in Swift 5 yet... This will produce the same effect as `compactMapValues`.

Same dictionary but with no optionals.

```
let cleanDictionary = originalDictionary.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }
```

Quick playground:

```
let originalDictionary = [
    "one": 1,
    "two": nil,
    "three": 3]

let cleanDictionary = originalDictionary.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }    
for element in cleanDictionary {
    print(element)
}
```

output:

> ["one": 1, "three": 3]

Comment: How to remove for empty String  "four" = "" ?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of the question, I suggest looking for it separately. This question is focused on nil values:)

Comment: Okay I will look it into another

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve this for a general case where NSNulls could be nested in the dictionary at any level, or even be part of an array:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {

func strippingNulls() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {

    var temp = self
    temp.stripNulls()
    return temp
}

mutating func stripNulls() {

    for (key, value) in self {
        if value is NSNull {
            removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
        if let values = value as? [Any] {
            var filtered = values.filter {!($0 is NSNull) }

            for (index, element) in filtered.enumerated() {
                if var nestedDict = element as? [String: Any] {
                    nestedDict.stripNulls()

                    if nestedDict.values.count > 0 {
                        filtered[index] = nestedDict as Any
                    } else {
                        filtered.remove(at: index)
                    }
                }
            }

            if filtered.count > 0 {
                self[key] = filtered
            } else {
                removeValue(forKey: key)
            }
        }

        if var nestedDict = value as? [String: Any] {

            nestedDict.stripNulls()

            if nestedDict.values.count > 0 {
                self[key] = nestedDict as Any
            } else {
                self.removeValue(forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I hope this is helpful to others *and* I welcome improvements!

(Note: this is Swift 4)

Comment: I'm trying to create a dictionary of values using `Mirror` to get all the properties of a class, chuck them in a `Dictionary`, and filter out the nil values. This code does not crash, but it doesn't remove nil values and their associated keys for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution, when `JSON` have `sub-dictionaries`.
This will go-through all the `dictionaries`, `sub-dictionaries` of `JSON` and remove NULL`(NSNull)` `key-value` pair from the `JSON`.

```
extension Dictionary {

    func removeNull() -> Dictionary {
        let mainDict = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary: self)
        for _dict in mainDict {
            if _dict.value is NSNull {
                mainDict.removeObject(forKey: _dict.key)
            }
            if _dict.value is NSDictionary {
                let test1 = (_dict.value as! NSDictionary).filter({ $0.value is NSNull }).map({ $0 })
                let mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary: _dict.value as! NSDictionary)
                for test in test1 {
                    mutableDict.removeObject(forKey: test.key)
                }
                mainDict.removeObject(forKey: _dict.key)
                mainDict.setValue(mutableDict, forKey: _dict.key as? String ?? "")
            }
            if _dict.value is NSArray {
                let mutableArray = NSMutableArray.init(object: _dict.value)
                for (index,element) in mutableArray.enumerated() where element is NSDictionary {
                    let test1 = (element as! NSDictionary).filter({ $0.value is NSNull }).map({ $0 })
                    let mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary: element as! NSDictionary)
                    for test in test1 {
                        mutableDict.removeObject(forKey: test.key)
                    }
                    mutableArray.replaceObject(at: index, with: mutableDict)
                }
                mainDict.removeObject(forKey: _dict.key)
                mainDict.setValue(mutableArray, forKey: _dict.key as? String ?? "")
            }
        }
        return mainDict as! Dictionary<Key, Value>
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim Null form NSDictionary to get ride of crash
Pass Dictionary to this function and get result as NSMutableDictionary

```
func trimNullFromDictionaryResponse(dic:NSDictionary) -> NSMutableDictionary {
    let allKeys = dic.allKeys
    let dicTrimNull = NSMutableDictionary()
    for i in 0...allKeys.count - 1 {
        let keyValue = dic[allKeys[i]]
        if keyValue is NSNull {
            dicTrimNull.setValue("", forKey: allKeys[i] as! String)
        }
        else {
            dicTrimNull.setValue(keyValue, forKey: allKeys[i] as! String)
        }
    }
    return dicTrimNull
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to unwrap it with the expected type of values and check for the nill or empty if yes then remove that value from the dictionary.

This will work if the values in the dictionary is has empty values

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  Collection+SF.swift
//  PanoAI
//
//  Created by Forever Positive on 2021/1/30.
//

import Foundation

extension Array where Element == Optional<Any>{
    var trimed:[Any] {
       var newArray = [Any]()
        for item in self{
            if let item = item as? [Any?] {
                newArray.append(contentsOf: item.trimed)
            }else if item is NSNull || item == nil {
                //skip
            }else if let item = item{
                newArray.append(item)
            }
        }
        return newArray
    }
}

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Optional<Any> {
    var trimed:[Key: Any] {
        return self.compactMapValues({ v in
            if let dic = v as? [String:Any?] {
                return dic.trimed
            }else if let _ = v as? NSNull {
                return nil;
            }else if let array = v as? [Any?] {
                return array.trimed;
            }else{
                return v;
            }
        })
    }
}

// MARK: - Usage
//let dic:[String:Any?] = ["a":"a","b":nil,"c":NSNull(),"d":["1":"1","2":nil,"3":NSNull(),"4":["a","b",nil,NSNull()]],"e":["a","b",nil,NSNull()]]
//print(dic.trimed)
```