# remove null values in json response swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, cocoa-touch

I'm getting this error :

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1114e4850) to 'NSString' (0x11065d2a8).

//These are my arrays
var snoArray:[Int] = []
var quote_idArray:[String] = []
var quote_amountArray:[String] = []
var dateArray:[String] = []
var timeArray:[String] = []
var perkilometerArray:[String] = []
var pertonArray:[String] = []

//My JSON response is like this.
["Response": {
Array =     (
            {
        date = "25-05-2018";
        perkilometer = 2;
        perton = "<null>";
        "quote_amount" = 1234;
        "quote_id" = 5b080f8aa082c;
        sno = 1;
        time = "18:58";
    },
            {
        date = "25-05-2018";
        perkilometer = 346;
        perton = "<null>";
        "quote_amount" = 230000;
        "quote_id" = 5b080ed57aa34;
        sno = 2;
        time = "18:55";
    }
);
"error_code" = 0;
message = SUCCESS;
status = SUCCESS;
}, "count": 2]

//I'm catching response like this...
if status == "SUCCESS" {
   if let array = res!["Array"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
      //    print(array.count)
      self.snoArray = array.map { $0["sno"]! } as! [Int]
      self.quote_idArray = array.map { $0["quote_id"]! } as! [String]
      self.quote_amountArray = array.map { $0["quote_amount"]! } as! [String]
      self.dateArray = array.map { $0["date"]! } as! [String]
      self.timeArray = array.map { $0["time"]! } as! [String]
      self.perkilometerArray = array.map { $0["perkilometer"]! } as! [String]
      //But here I'm getting null values and app crashed
      self.pertonArray = array.map { $0["perton"]! } as! [String]
   }
} 

//When I write like this, it's printing : [<null>, <null>]
let perTon = array.compactMap({ $0 ["perton"]})
 print(perTon) // Output: [<null>, <null>]
```

I referred this link : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-non-nil-values-in-an-array-of-optionals/

Here i want to remove null values from self.pertonArray and want to print empty self.pertonArray([ , ]).

If suppose I get response like this how to solve this problem.

```
["Response": {
Array =     (
            {
        date = "25-05-2018";
        perkilometer = 2;
        perton = "something";
        "quote_amount" = 1234;
        "quote_id" = 5b080f8aa082c;
        sno = 1;
        time = "18:58";
    },
            {
        date = "25-05-2018";
        perkilometer = 346;
        perton = "<null>";
        "quote_amount" = 230000;
        "quote_id" = 5b080ed57aa34;
        sno = 2;
        time = "18:55";
    }
);
"error_code" = 0;
message = SUCCESS;
status = SUCCESS;
}, "count": 2]
```

How to solve this problem....

Comment: don't cast it as string use string interpolation like `"\(yourVariable)"` this will not cause crash

Comment: @ Devil Decoder can you post the  answer, I will accept it...

Comment: Don't force unwrap things and you will save many more crashes like this. Use guard let/if let.

Comment: @ Sharad Chauhan can you post best solution for me.

Comment: I recommend using [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) for dealing with JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: How to remove a null value from Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044095/swift-how-to-remove-a-null-value-from-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to remove nil from JSON when binding.
But here is one according to your code.

```
if status == "SUCCESS" {
   if let array = res!["Array"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
      //    print(array.count)
      self.snoArray = array.map { ($0["sno"] as? Int) ?? 0 }
      self.quote_idArray = array.map { ($0["quote_id"] as? String) ?? "" }
      self.quote_amountArray = array.map { ($0["quote_amount"] as? String) ?? "" }
      self.dateArray = array.map { ($0["date"] as? String) ?? "" }
      self.timeArray = array.map { ($0["time"] as? String) ?? ""} 
      self.perkilometerArray = array.map { ($0["perkilometer"] as? String) ?? "" }

      // You get error here with null values
      // here is how it's fixed
      self.pertonArray = array.map { ($0["perton"] as? String) ?? "" }
   }
}
```

It's a good practice to not use `Force Unwrapping` when binding json because you will never be sure there will be no null or incorrect data (You expect Int but the value is String as sent from Server).

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer. Please respond fro me.

Answer (score 1):

use string interpolation to parse value

like in your response

you want to get `perton`

```
let value = ((responce as! Array)[indexofarray] as! Dictionary<string,any>)["perton"]
let perton = "\(value ?? "")"
```

this will return `something` for first index and for second index it will return `<null>` in string