# Checking if [NSObject : AnyObject]! is NSNull in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, type-safety

My project uses both Swift and Objective C. I have a singleton written in Objective C which as a property of the type NSDictionary.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *currentDictionary;
```

This is an old class that's being used throughout my project. I am trying to use this class in a Swift class like this

```
if let dict = DataManager.sharedManager().currentDictionary
{
   // 
}
```

The problem i am facing is that currentDictionary is being set using data from the server. At times this might be

In Objective C classes, i can handle the situation with the following check

```
if ([currentDictionary isKindOfClass: [NSNull class]])
{
   // Do nothing
}
```

But i am not sure how to implement a similar check in Swift. I tried the following

```
if let data = DataManager.sharedManager().currentDictionary as? NSNull
{
    return 
}
```

But it doesn't work and also i get a compiler warning :

"Cast from "[NSObject : AnyObject]!" to unrelated type "NSNull" always fails"

This is different from checking for Null values within the dicitonary as they will be 'AnyObject's and i can try casting them into the type i want to check.

Can someone please provide any pointers on how to handle this situation properly

Comment: The `NSDictionary` should ***never*** be of type `NSNull`. Its content may be, but not the dictionary itself.

Comment: This post is probably useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026609/detect-a-null-value-in-nsdictionary

Comment: @luk2302 .. Yes , it should not be. I have communicated the same with the server side. But i would like to add a safety check at the client as well.

Comment: As @luk2302 says: If there is a problem, you should have nil, but **NEVER EVER** NSNull.

Comment: There is nothing to communicate. It **MUST NOT** be `NSNull`. There is a reason the type is specified! The *only* option for you is to parse the response you receive from the server and decide wether or not it is actual content -> put it inside the dictionary **or** if it is `null`, `nil` or whatever you either create an empty dictionary or set the dictionary to `nil`, you **do not** set the dictionary *itself* to `NSNull`. The same way you do not set it to literally `@"no value present"` or `@(-2)`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if the variable can contain something else that `NSDictionary`, don't set its type to `NSDictionary`. Swift is type safe and it will trust the declared type.

The easiest workaround would be to make it `id` in Objective-C.

Then in Swift you can simply:

```
guard let data = DataManager.sharedManager().currentDictionary as? NSDictionary else {
    return 
}
```

If you can't change the original code, just create a Swift accessor with correct type using a category, e.g.

```
@interface DataManager (Swift)

// solution 1, will be converted to AnyObject in Swift
- (id)currentDictionaryForSwift1;

// solution 2, let's handle NSNull internally, don't propagate it to Swift
- (NSDictionary *)currentDictionaryForSwift2;

@end

@implementation DataManager

- (id)currentDictionaryForSwift1 {
   return self.currentDictionary;
}  

- (NSDictionary *)currentDictionaryForSwift2 {
   if (self.currentDictionary == [NSNull null]) { 
      return nil;
   }

   return self.currentDictionary;
}    

@end
```

I would recommend you to handle `NSNull` internally. There should be no need to for other code to handle `nil` and `NSNull` separately.

You could actually solve it already in the getter:

```
- (NSDictionary *)currentDictionary {
   if (_currentDictionary == [NSNull null]) {
      return nil;
   }

   return _currentDictionary;
}
```

or in the setter

```
- (void)setCurrentDictionary:(NSDictionary *)currentDictionary {
    if (currentDictionary == [NSNull null]) {
       _currentDictionary = nil;
    } else {
       _currentDictionary = currentDictionary;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are multiple solutions but the best solution should improve even your Obj-C code. The difference between `NSNull` and `nil` should be handled locally and not propagated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate wether `currentDictionary` is `nil` or not, you can use:

```
guard let currentDictionary = DataManager.sharedManager().currentDictionary else {
    return
}
```

Replace `guard-else` statement with `if-else` if you don't want to return early.

If you want to validate contents of `currentDictionary` is `NSNull` or not:

```
if let value = DataManager.sharedManager().currentDictionary["key"] {
    // do something with value
}
```

Comment: I did try the guard statement , but it doesn't help as well. I think it checks for nil , which fails as there is in fact a NSNull object

Comment: What if you use `guard DataManager.sharedManager().currentDictionary is NSNull else { return }`?

Comment: The same warning is generated